# No Bluetooth Found

Tags: bluetooth

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 ,32bit os, but somehow i am getting **

> "BLUETOOTH NOT FOUND plug in a dongle to use bluetooth"

** message while trying to connect the bluetooth. Kindly help to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Try `rfkill unblock bluetooth` in a terminal.

Comment: Any luck with fixing this? I also have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after I did an update, then after I turned bluetooth off, when I turned it back on it stopped working with exactly that message.

The solution was to restart my computer.